# Transposed dataframe to LaTeX

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, latex, pandas-styles

I am not able to change the number format in the LaTeX output of the library Pandas.

Consider this example:

```
import pandas as pd

values = [ { "id":"id1", "c1":1e-10, "c2":int(1000) }]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(values).set_index("id")
print(df)
```

with output:

```
               c1    c2
id                     
id1  1.000000e-10  1000
```

Let's say that I want `c1` formatted with two decimal places, `c2` as an integer:

```
s = df.style
s.clear()
s.format({ "c1":"{:.2f}", "c2":"{:d}" })
print(s.to_latex())
```

with output:

```
\begin{tabular}{lrr}
 & c1 & c2 \\
id &  &  \\
id1 & 0.00 & 1000 \\
\end{tabular}
```

However, I do not need a LaTeX table for `df` but for `df.T`.

**Question**: since I can specify the styles only for the columns (at least it seems so in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.format.html)), **how can I specify the row-based output format for `df.T`?**

If I simply write this:

```
dft = df.T
s2 = dft.style
# s2.clear()   # nothing changes with this instruction
print(s2.to_latex())
```

it is ever worse as I get:

```
\begin{tabular}{lr}
id & id1 \\
c1 & 0.000000 \\
c2 & 1000.000000 \\
\end{tabular}
```

where even the integer (the one with value `int(1000)`) became a float using the default style/format.

I played with the `subset` parameter and various slices with no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As workaround, you can format each value to its correct one with:

```
fmt = { "c1":"{:.2f}", "c2":"{:d}" }
df_print = df.apply(lambda x: [fmt[x.name].format(v) for v in x])
print(df_print.T.style.to_latex())
```

Output:

```
\begin{tabular}{ll}
{id} & {id1} \\
c1 & 0.00 \\
c2 & 1000 \\
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: I have learned something with your answer: The use of dictionaries as normal functions (that is, that `{'a': 2, 'b': 3}['b']` is valid and returns `3`). Thanks, @Corralien! +1

Comment: Thanks for the workaround, that, frankly, I did not think of. Is this the only way? Is it really not possible to specify a row-based formatter?

Comment: @AntonioSesto. You can do whatever you want with the colors, but for string formatting it's always per column :-( Hope my answer solves your problem for now :-)